# SharePoint Profile Sync Exclusion Filters

Tags: 2010, user-profile, profile-sync

If an exlcusion filter is added to a profile sync connection AFTER the profiles have already been imported, when are the newly excluded profiles purged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Full synchronization to apply the filter immediately.